# Using Stirling's approximation

Tags: calculus

I am reading an article and in one section it uses stirling's approximation.
I decided to do the math and check if it's ok, but I got a different result than the one in the article.

[image: A screenshot of the use of stirling's approximation]

Where r,p are natural numbers.

I used the "often written" part in [Wikipidia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (the one with the 'e' in it)

How did the article got this result ?

Comment: We need a direction for a limit I guess.  Say, $r$ is fixed but $p \to \infty$.  Is that what you want?  To tell, we need to know more than just "an article".

Comment: @GEdgar- you are right, sorry! r is fixed and p tends to infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result mentioned in the paper you are reading holds in the sense that, for every fixed $r\gt2$,
$$
\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}\frac1p\log{(r-1)p\choose p}=\log c(r),\quad \text{with}\quad c(r)=\frac{(r-1)^{r-1}}{(r-2)^{r-2}}.
$$
In other words, when $p\to\infty$,
$$
{(r-1)p\choose p}=c(r)^{p+o(p)}.
$$
[Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (which you link to) yields the (stronger, non logarithmic) equivalent
$$
{(r-1)p\choose p}=c(r)^p\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{p}}\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot\sqrt\frac{r-1}{r-2}\cdot(1+o(1)).
$$

Comment: What is the base for the log ? if it's p I understand the result in the article. what did you use for your approximation (what did you substitute  n! for ?)

Comment: Thank you for the extra explanation! are you sure that it's a small o and not O ?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: very interesting. Do you have a reference to the version of Stirling's approximation you are using, or maybe you have another reason for this ? (all versions I know are with big O...)

Comment: Yes: the second formula on the WP page you linked to says that $n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot(n/\mathrm e)^n\cdot(1+o(1))$. You might want to check again your use of [Bachmann-Landau notations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: oh I see, thanks again!